# Google domain setup on GCP VM with nginx.?

Tags: nginx, https, google-cloud-platform, dns

Google domain name pointing at external IP of GCP compute engine with nginx installed and app in `/var/www/html`. Have google site verification of property code.  I need HTTPS setup. Do I need Lets Encrypt? Why is it so difficult to establish HTTPS?

None of the dozens of sites nothing here in tag search or on GCP. Nginx has how to setup in `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` but my site is visible http using my external IP but not the HTTPS domain name.

Comment: Setting up HTTPS via Let's Encrypt is easy. There are hundreds of step-by-step documents on the Internet. Configuring SSL for nginx is also easy. Here is an example tutorial: https://www.nginx.com/blog/using-free-ssltls-certificates-from-lets-encrypt-with-nginx/ I would practice on a test instance in the cloud until the pieces make sense to you. Do not try this on a live system as a problem will take the site down.

Comment: Thanks John, I was hoping there was some metadata on the VM I could add that lets Google domain know it was me using their cloud VM and to authenticate me. Like the Google site verification code I got showing it is my temporary property.  I added openssl key and cert right in the conf file.  Nginx has so many advanced features. I was looking for a short cut in this case around let's encrypt. I will try this next.